# Installing Xampp on Ubuntu 16.04 gives error command not found

Tags: permissions, filesystem, xampp

I know this seems a duplicate question but no answer I have found solves my problem.  I have looked at instructions on Apache Friends but no success.  I still get an error

```
command not found
```

I know the file exits in Downloads and I can double click it, the Bitnami splash screen shows, but then I get an error that 'There has been an error. This installer requires root privileges.  Please become a superuser before running installer.'  I have checked the properties and it is set to Run as executable and the owner is Me.

Current error message when run from inside the Downloads folder is

```
sudo: xampp-linux-x64-5.6.30-1-installer.run: command not found
```

There were 2 similar questions but no anwer was ever found.  I have googled for assistance, searched Ubuntu, posted on Apache Friends but still no solution.
Please can someone assist - Thankyou

Comment: You can go through the instructions that has been given in this [website](https://www.apachefriends.org/faq_linux.html).
Before doing that enter the directory in the terminal where the installer has been downloaded  has `$ cd Downloads` and enter into superuser mode to continue

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the exact commands you are typing - not just the errors

Comment: I don't get it why do you install xampp on ubuntu. Xampp is for windows machines where you can't have a web server so easily. On Ubuntu you can simply install Nginx with php and mysql and that's it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to change directory to Downloads:

```
cd Downloads/
```

You need to make the file executable :

```
sudo chmod +x xampp-linux-x64-5.6.30-1-installer.run
```

Then run the file:

```
sudo ./xampp-linux-x64-5.6.30-1-installer.run
```

Answer (score 0):

Once it's downloaded, add execute permissions to the installation file, then execute it.

```
$ chmod +x xampp-linux-*-installer.run

$ sudo ./xampp-linux-*-installer.run
```